# Loft bed design question

Tags: attic, construction, design, project-planning

I am building a twin loft bed. The loft would be a DIY bed with 4 legs, but have a design challenge on one leg side of loft bed.

There is an air floor register located to one of the 4th leg.

So how close can loft bed’s leg be to the register?

The floor joist is parallel to the register (long side) and then downstairs is finished.

What is best way to go ?

[image]

Comment: I would probably place the leg on one of the short sides, instead of the long side farthest from the wall, in case you are worried about floor support.  Most floors should support the leg where ever.  If that is older metal register, it might support the leg also, when moving the bed.

Comment: The leg can be _on_ the _edge_ of the register, theoretically. That should be fully supported by the subfloor underneath. Probably best not to do that, though. There is no "best" answer that we can provide that will cover every situation, but you may consider changing the size or design of the loft so the leg will be a little farther away from the register. You could make the legs a different shape so they go around the register. Since you haven't shared your design, it's hard to comment, let alone answer... Please [edit] your question with a drawing of your design.

Comment: Are you saying the leg would be in the area where the register is, all things being equal?  Personally, I'd simply bridge the register—build an open-sided box over the register, and make the leg there shorter than the others so that it rests upon the top of the box.  Assuming the bed isn't intended to be anchored to the wall.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions:

(1) Move the leg a little to the inside of the bed itself, say 8" to the inside.

(2) Nail/screw a 2x4 against the wall, nailed to the studs. Then have the bed rest against this.